# Bean scope. Does an bean get instantiated more than once in a form?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I have problems understanding the scope of the player variable. This will work.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="playerMenu" value="#{player.firstName}" onchange="submit();"
                    valueChangeListener="#{player.eventNameChanged}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{serviceHCP.allPlayers}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="#{player.combinedName}"></h:outputText>
```

This will correctly set the outputText to the playerCombined name. that is set in the event method.

It will also work with this

```
        <h:commandButton value="Visa lista" action="#{serviceSeries.getSeriesForPlayerInfo(club.name, player.firstName, serieType.serie_type, calendarBean) }">
        </h:commandButton>
```

But that I don't understand is why I can't send in player instead of player.firstName? If I send player it will always end up being null. if I send player.firstName it's instantiated correctly. I will also not work if I do player.combinedName. It seems like they are two completely different instances of the class.

It makes me even more confused when this part of the code does what I want. However that is a primefaces component so I don't know if that has something to do with it?

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" id="popupButtonCal" showOn="button" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" >
                    </p:calendar>


public List<Player> getAllPlayers() {

if (factory == null) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
}

EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
//Order by the matchdate.
//Query q = em.createQuery("select t from DBTest t");
Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Player t");

List<Player> players = q.getResultList();
for (Player aPlayer : players) {
  System.out.println(aPlayer);
}
System.out.println("Size: " + players.size());

em.close();

return players;
```

}

Comment: The reason you can't 'send' `player` is probably because it cannot be cast into a primitive type. But you can send the player id, then in the backing bean search the player object from `List<Player>`. If you want to select a player , then you need a converter. See the Pojo and Content with Filter examples here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

Comment: Yes it occured to me that that might be the case. But then I don't understand why the calendarBean can be sent?

Comment: @user2130951 what are the scopes of `player` and `serviceSeries`?

Comment: They are session beans. Just like the calendarBean.

Comment: @user2130951 - if they're session beans, why do you need to pass them around in the view? Why not just inject one bean into the other and perform your operation on the fields of the injected bean?

Comment: Can you show how to do that ?